# Cannot make this box responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put some content into a box, but I cannot make the text and the button to fit into the box on medium and small screens.
I have tried some methods, but none of them worked so far.

Here is my current code:

```css
* {
  background: #0E2A38;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  height: 230px;
  background: green;
}

.explore {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 25px;
    height: 230px;
    color: white;
    background: #3161a3;
}

#exploreButton {
    width: 85%;
    color: #3161a3;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="explore">
      <p id="exploreTitle">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto</p>
      <p id="exploreParagraph">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Recusandae dicta ut illo reiciendis delectus maiores dicta.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="exploreButton">Explore</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="explore">
```

It will make the divs responsive.
It will get full width on screens below 768px (md breakpoint).
You can change md by sm if you want.
[More about bootstrap breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).

Comment: But I don't want the explore-div to have 12 colons, never

Answer (score 0):

it is good to use the css min-width property because you have used all containers and elements in static voltage, look at my solution

```css
body {
  background: #0E2A38;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  height: 230px;
  background: green;
}

.explore {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 25px;
    height: 230px;
    color: white;
    background: #3161a3;
    min-width:300px;
}

#exploreButton {
    width: 85%;
    color: #3161a3;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="explore">
      <p id="exploreTitle">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto</p>
      <p id="exploreParagraph">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Recusandae dicta ut illo reiciendis delectus maiores dicta.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="exploreButton">Explore</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can also use the overflow:hidden property to hide the content or overflow:auto to use scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  background: #0E2A38;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  height: 230px;
  background: green;
}

p {
    word-break: break-word;
}

.explore {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 25px;
    color: white;
    background: #3161a3;
}

#exploreButton {
    width: 85%;
    color: #3161a3;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="explore">
        <p id="exploreTitle">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto</p>
        <p id="exploreParagraph">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          Recusandae dicta ut illo reiciendis delectus maiores dicta.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="exploreButton">Explore</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `.container` before using `.row` also avoid using height. For aligning both divs vertically i have used `.align-items-center`. For reference go through
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ 
this link